# clearing Zombie-cookies

Tags: security, safari

HELP!  I'm being eaten alive by Zombie-cookies!

I Have been attempting to clear zombie-cookies from all HTML5 storage locations without success. I am using Safari 5.1.10 and System 10.6.8

Reseting Safari,emptying the catch or setting private browsing does NOT empty the relevant HTML5 storage locations, as ~ 100 zombie-cookies reappear spontaneously over ~ 10 minutes, even without visiting any web pages other than the startup page.

Disabling Javascript, and disallowing Java  and disallowing all other plug-ins  blocks some of these zombie cookies from reappearing, but MANY still rapidly repopulate the cookies list.

Disabling catches in the Develop menu does seem to block some but NOT all of these from repopulating, but it also has the unwanted effect of preventing many web features from functioning properly.

Going to Library/Safari/LocalStorage and secure trash emptying these files also does NOT work, as most repopulate the cookies list again after reopening Safari.

I have also gone to the online Adobe site and set my preferences to prevent Local shared objects (LSOs), more commonly called Flash cookies (due to their similarities with HTTP cookies), from appearing on my computer.  These are pieces of data that websites which use Adobe Flash may store on a user's computer. Local shared objects are used by all versions of Adobe Flash Player and version 6 and above of Macromedia's now-obsolete Flash Player.
This strategy also did NOT stop most Zombie-cookies from reappearing.

It is my understanding that zombie cookies can also be lurking in any of the following locations:

```
Standard HTTP cookies
Storing cookies in and reading out web history
Storing cookies in HTTP ETags
Internet Explorer userData storage (starting IE9, userData is no longer supported)
HTML5 Session Storage
HTML5 Local Storage
HTML5 Global Storage
HTML5 Database Storage via SQLite
Storing cookies in RGB values of auto-generated, force-cached PNGs using HTML5 Canvas tag to read pixels (cookies) back out
Local Shared Objects
Silverlight Isolated Storage
Cookie syncing scripts that function as a cache cookie and respawn the MUID cookie
```

I'm told that failing to delete the storage from any and all of these or other unknown devious locations will lead again to the Zombie-cookie Apocalypse once more. Does anyone have any strategies regarding how to permanently remove Zombie-cookies, or better yet, prevent them from getting their teeth into your computer to start with?

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Source [disable tracking cookies](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2738661?start=0&tstart=0)

> 1. Backup your important data such as usernames, passwords, etc.
> 2. Install Safari Cookies from http://sweetpproductions.com/safaricookies or your Mac software site.
> 3. Restart Safari.
> 4. Within Safari Cookies, set your preferences. Set your favorite cookies, flash cookies, and databases.
> 5. Begin using Safari.
> 6. When you need to clear cookies, flash cookies, and databases; restart Safari.
> 7. If there is a technical difficulty between Safari (e.g. 5.1.1) and Safari Cookie (e.g. 1.8); go to menu bar > Safari > Empty Cache... (or
>      command + option + E).
> 8. a. Wait at least one minute for the undesired data to disappear. The more data, the longer this process.
> 9. b. Or restart Safari.
> 10. Only the favorite items should be present.
> 11. If the above does not work, repeat steps 1-6.
> 12. Go to menu bar > Safari > Perferences > Privacy > Remove All Website Data... (Caution: favorite and non-favorite items will be
>       deleted).
> 13. a. Wait at least one minute. The more data, the longer this process.
> 14. b. Or restart Safari.
> 15. No cookies, flash cookies, or databases should be present (favorite or non-favorite).